# how to define public variable in java which cannot be modified

Tags: java, class, variables, object

I would like every object of a class be able to access a class variable but don't want to get modified outside class.
For example the way Array.length is used.

But would also like to have a method in class which conditionally modifies this variable.

Basically this usage is for a resizing object array implementation, where length of object array can change dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be a few confusing points here.

> I would like every object of a class be able to access a class variable but don't want to get modified outside class. For example the way Array.length is used.

`Array.length` is (effectively) a final field - an array's length in Java cannot change, so it cannot be modified from inside *or* outside the class.

> But would also like to have a method in class which conditionally modifies this variable.

If a variable is final, as the `length` field in array, then its value cannot be modified at all, by anything.

You're not going to get this level of control from a field directly. Instead you should follow the standard getter pattern - make the field private and non-final, provide a public method to get its value (`getLength()` for example) and then set it as you need to within that class. This gives you the flexibility to change the value from within the class as you need to, while still allowing the value to be read from anywhere else.

Comment: I understand the usage of getter and setters. But I am trying implement an array like length feature where length is not fixed and can change based on new objects added. But I was curious if there is a way achieve this without having to declare a new method. If that is not tried by anybody or is not possible, I guess I will resort to traditional ways. I am a new learner.

Comment: @YogeshLuthra You say - `array like length feature where length is not fixed and can change based on new objects added`. However, this is incorrect - an array's length *is* fixed. The `ArrayList` collection class has a length that is not fixed (a dynamic size), but as a result you will find the length is obtained via a getter method (`getSize()`), not a final variable.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.length` is marked `final` and hence cannot be modified after the constructor is returned. I don't know what you're talking about there.

I guess, you want a private field with public getters and private setters?

```
private int someField = 0;

public int getSomeField() { return someField; }

private void setSomeField(int newValue) {
    if (someCondition) {
        someField = newValue;
    }
}
```

- Since both `someField` and `setSomeField` are private, no code outside of this class can modify the value of `someField`.
- Code outside can only get the value of `someField`.
- Code inside the class can conditionally set the value of `someField` by calling `setSomeField`.

Requirements met!

Answer (score 0):

I think what I was trying to do could be accomplished by ArrayList implementation. Thanks for your replies.